# Excel VBA highlight entire column according to today's date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the following data in my excel table. My requirements is to highlight the the entire column of my current date.
[image: my excel table]

I have found a code where it search through my dates and select the today's date. However when i try to move to another cell to input some data, it keeps on going back to the selected date and i was unable to do key in. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)     
  Dim TodaysDate As Date
  Dim Rng As Range

  TodaysDate = CLng(Date)
  With Rows("1:1")
  Set Rng = .Find(what:=TodaysDate, _
  after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  lookat:=xlWhole, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
 Application.Goto Rng, True
Else

'Give a message that today's date was not found

  MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
End With`
```

The above code doesn't include the highlighting part yet since i have no idea how to do it since i just learn to do VBA since yesterday.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim TodaysDate As Date
  Dim Rng As Range

  TodaysDate = CLng(Date)
  With Rows("1:1")
  Set Rng = .Find(what:=TodaysDate, _
  after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  lookat:=xlWhole, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
Rng.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = vbMagenta
Else

'Give a message that today's date was not found

  MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the whole VBA and use conditional formatting. See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: thank you for your immediate reply but which conditional formatting did you use?

Comment: See the screenshot. Select Column DH, select conditional formatting, Use a formula...., in the formula bos of the conditional formatting window enter =DH$1=TODAY(), Click on the Format button and select the Fill color you would like to use. Click OK. You can then use the format painter to copy this format to all other columns

Comment: Now i get it.. But if this only works with the current sheet, this wont work if i have to open another new sheet and that would not be convenient if i have to do the repetitive task.

Comment: True. See second answer for a fixed up VBA solution